# Returning a double with a loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, return

I am trying to return a double from a simple for loop.  For some reason I keep getting a error message saying the method is missing a return statement.

Here is my code:

```
public static double quantitytable(){

    for(double x=1; x<=1000; x=x+100){    
           return x;
    }

}
```

Comment: That's just equivalent to `return 1;`...

Comment: Also, you should *never* use a `double` as a loop variable, or the gods of IEEE floating point will get you eventually.

Comment: I assume you meant to return x after the loop is done?

Comment: The reason I think it's giving you that warning is that the compiler can't tell if "x<=1000" is ever going to be true.  (We know it is, but it's not a given.)  Because of this, the loop may not execute.  If it doesn't execute, then it will fall through.  And you don't have a "return" statement after the loop.

Comment: Others have answered why the compiler would complain - what is your expected output?

Answer (score 5):

Your loop does not make sense: as soon as you return, looping is over. Essentially, your program is equivalent to this:

```
public static double quantitytable(){
    return 1;
}
```

If you would like to return multiple items from a method, return an array or a Java collection:

```
public static List<Double> quantitytable() {
    List<Double> res = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for(double x=1 ; x<=1000 ; x += 100) {
       res.add(x);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, every code path has to return a value. The compiler doesn't try to prove that the `for` loop returns in all cases (even though we can tell it does), and thus it thinks that control could go past the end of the for loop (so it demands a `return` statement after the `for` loop).

Answer (score 1):

your code will return straight away you know. while its in the first iteration

```
double x=1 
      for(; x<=1000; x+=100){    
               return x;}

    }
```